# How to upgrade powershell from 5.1 to 7.1 for runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I have a runbook, which I have been using for several years (with modifications).  When created, it was defined to use Powershell version 5.1.  The runbook is run daily through Automation.

I am now beginning to use Powershell 7.1 elsewhere, and would therefore like also to use that version in this runbook.  But I cannot find ways to upgrade from Powershell 5.1 to 7.1.

How can I accomblish this task?

I have search through all runbook related properties in Azure, and tried to find a solution through Google, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/637711/how-to-use-powershell-to-import-a-runbook-and-set) discussion, the migration from PowerShell `5.1` to the most recent releases (`7.1 or 7.2`) is still processing. The update for altering existing runtime versions has not yet been provided.

As a workaround, if you need to update the `PowerShell` runtime version go to the below path and update Az modules to `7.1`. It will automatically take `PowerShell 7.1` runtime modules once you updated.

*Path:* `Automation account >> Shared resources >> Modules >> Update Az Modules`

[image]

Alternatively, you can use PowerShell command
`Set-AzAutomationModule` as another workaround to achieve your requirement.

Here I've downloaded the required PowerShell module from [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/10.4.1) and uploaded the module from local to Azure storage container. And later I provided the uploaded blob URL in place of `ContentLinkUri` with the link version as shown.

```
Set-AzAutomationModule -AutomationAccountName "newauto" -Name "Az" -ContentLinkUri "https://stprojectjm.blob.core.windows.net/new/az.10.4.1.nupkg" -ContentLinkVersion "10.4.1" -ResourceGroupName "xxxx"
```

[image]